# bootstrap box spaning rows right side img element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

there's some problems with responsive grid system to me.

http://imageshack.com/a/img537/9687/4H48G0.jpg

http://imageshack.com/a/img539/8265/ANvr0Y.jpg - problem is here

**My source code:**

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css"> 
        .wrapper {

          height: 100%;

        text-align: center;

          margin: 0 auto;
        }
        img { max-width:100% !important;
            height:auto;
            display:block;
          }
        .text { 
            color: #fff;
            text-shadow:0px 2px 10px #000;
            height: 100%;
            left: 0;
            position: absolute;
            text-align: center;
            top: 0;
            font-size: 22px;
            width: 100%;}
        .box {
            border: 1px dashed #000;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
        }

        .tb_floater {
            font-size: 1.5em;
            margin-top: 20%;
            padding-top: 10%;

        }
        .box.tall {
            height: 300px;
        }
        .box.tall > a > img {
            height: auto;
        }
        </style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 box tall">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://www.websailer.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/www_image.jpg">
            </a>
        <div class="text tall">
          <div class="tb_floater">
            <p>Loren ipsum shit amet<br/>Loren ipsum</p>
          </div>
    </div>
   </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 box" style="height:150px;">.col-xs-6 .col-md-6</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2 box" style="height:150px;">.col-xs-6 .col-md-2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2 box" style="height:150px;">.col-xs-6 .col-md-2</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 box" style="height:150px;">.col-xs-6 .col-md-6</div>

</div>
  <div class="row">
<div class="pull-right col-xs-6 col-md-4 box tall">
      <a href="#">
          <img src="http://www.websailer.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/www_image.jpg">
          </a>
        <div class="text tall">
          <div class="tb_floater">
            <p>Loren ipsum shit amet<br/>Loren ipsum</p>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>


       <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2 box" style="height:150px;">.col-xs-6 .col-md-6</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 box" style="height:150px;">.col-xs-6 .col-md-2</div> 
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2 box" style="height:150px;">.col-xs-6 .col-md-6</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 box" style="height:150px;">.col-xs-6 .col-md-2</div>


</div>
```

That empty field is problem when i resize the browser, any solution ?

Comment: can you share your custom css too?

Comment: I did some live example of your sample code and don't see any problems. Example is [here](http://codepen.io/neilhem/full/dvacI/). P.S. I used Bootstrap v3.2.0

Comment: What do u mean by empty field?? i dont see any issue in ur code